# Expression Engine if statement display new page

Tags: expressionengine

I wish to display a new page when the confirm status is met using expression engine. Please see code below:

```
<div class="column">
<p><button type="submit" class="submit" name="submit"><span>Submit Order</span></button> </p>        
{if segment_2 == "confirm"}
{/exp:channel:Confirmation}
{/if}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a template that displays a confirmation message you can redirect to it inside a conditional:

```
{if segment_2 == "confirm"}
    {redirect="template_group/template"}
{/if}
```

Though there might be a better way depending on what was used to create the form. Both [Channel Form (Safecracker)](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_form/#return) and [Freeform](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#return) accept a `return=""` parameter that you can use to redirect people on submission.